# Using functional application ID could not create object for WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Tags: excel, wsh

- Maestro runs with functional application ID and calls a Powershell script file

  - The PS script file calls a batch file - Run.bat

    - The batch file calls a Windows Script file (`cscript.exe ...xxx.wsf`)

      - The WSF runs a VBS program

        - It calls an Excel macro.

But the VBS program fails in the step where it tries to create Excel object and fails with the message "Could not create an object named excel.Application".

This script is working when user manually executes run.bat file.

Maestro also is working when functional application id credentials were used to login the server while maestro runs Run.batch file.

Please help why maestro could not create excel object in non-interactive mode i.e. user who runs the process is not actively logged in to the server.

Code in run.bat file:

```
cscript.exe ..\..\run.wsf
```

Code in run.wsf file:

```
<script language="vbscript" src="..\Run.vbs"></script>
```

Code in run.vbs file:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application") -- Program fails here
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fnGetAbsolutePath(xlsFile))
```

Comment: You'll have to show us the relevant code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Excel dcom-identity settings had been set as  "interactive user" in that server which caused non-interactive excel requests run using interactive user's id. When I changed the setting below, it worked.

1: start->run and type 'DCOMCNFG'

2: Open 'DCOM Config' and locate 'Microsoft Excel Application'

3: Set its identity to 'The Launching User'.